# Restler 404 Error

Tags: php, restler

i have just started to create an api with Restler and have the follwoing code.

**index.php**

```
require_once '../vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Defaults;
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
Defaults::$useUrlBasedVersioning = true;
$r = new Restler();
$r->setAPIVersion(1);
$r->setSupportedFormats('XmlFormat', 'JsonFormat');
$r->addAPIClass('Info', '');
$r->addAPIClass('Info');
$r->addAPIClass('getList');
$r->handle();
```

**info.php**

```
<?php
class Info {
    function index() {
        return "Version 1.0.0";
    }
}
?>
```

**v1/getList.php**

```
<?php
namespace v1;
use stdClass;
class getList
{
    function index()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    function newest() {
        return "hello2";
    }
}
```

I'm testing it with xampp on a windows machine and *localhost/api/* is mapped to the public folder.
When i open *localhost/api/* in the browser it will show *Version 1.0* as expected. But when i open *info* or *getList* i get a 404 error from apache.

How can i fix it?
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your `/api/.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```